# How can we find number of current user sessions in azure account via portal itself or programatically(powershell)?

Tags: azure, powershell

How can we find  number of current user sessions in azure account  via portal itself or programatically(powershell)?
We are using powershell to connect with azure account and using azure resources. we  are runing a no of scripts in parallel.need to check whether disconnect(Disconnect-AzureRmAccount) at the end of every script is needed or not.Does Azure disconnect itself if session is no more in use?
The problem we are facing is when a no of scripts are running parallerly, some scripts fail due to disconnect command that is probably triggered by some other script as we are using same account and using same resource.

Answer (score 0):

Like all PowerShell remoting, when you terminate your Shell, all sessions in that Shell is killed along with it.

Unless you specifically want to close down your RM connection in a script for a logical reason, you can void out that part.

When you have run all scripts that you want in a session, terminating the shell it self (or when the task that runs dies) the session goes with it.

Comment: how can i verify session count on azure ? is there any way to check powershell session ?

Comment: You cannot in Azure see the amount of connections you have to my knowledge. You can find out how many instances you have running in your current session, but if it is from different sessions / machines you cannot ask Azure how many remote sessions it has to my knowledge. You will have to check against what you expect is finished. Say if one script spins up a VM, other scripts would have to check if the is there before they do their thing.